# Is my interpretation of these open and closed sets correct?

Tags: general-topology

Given the space $\mathbb{N}$, with the topology $U\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ if $2n-1 \in U \implies 2n\in U$. Describe what the open and closed sets under this topology would like like in the space.

**My Attempt:** A set is open if it can be written as $(a,\infty)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$. And a closed set can be written as $[b,c]$ for $b\geq 1, c < \infty$.
How would I prove that this is this correct (or is it even correct)?

Comment: Something is wrong with “∈ℕ ”. Do you mean ”$U \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is open”?

Comment: is $\{1,2\}$ open in this topology? Is $\{2,3\}$ open in this topology?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang $U\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is open when $2n-1 \in U \implies 2n\in U$. So, {1,2} and {2,3} are in U. But I don't know how to prove what the open sets would look like.

Comment: Notice that $3 = 2 \times 2 - 1$ is in $\{2,3\}$, but $2 \times 2 = 4$ is not. So $\{2,3\}$ is **not** open in this topology.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang So what would determine which sets are open and closed? to generalize this

Comment: That's hard to say. The definition *already* gives a pretty good description of which sets are open, so I'm not exactly sure what the problem is looking for. You could give a basis for the topology—is there some subfamily such that every open set is a union of members of the family?

Answer (score 1):

Each subset $\{2n-1,2n\}$ is a connected component of the space and is isomorphic to the Sierpinski space.  So the space can be described as the topological sum of a countable number of [Sierpinski spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).  From this I leave it to you to describe the open and closed sets in the space, but ask if you run into problems.

It's example #55 in the book *Counterexamples in Topology* from Steen & Seebach, also described in detail [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000047/properties) in pi-base.